# Multicolumn Model for QCompleter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I'm trying to work with QCompleter for autocompletion on a QComboBox. The two pictures below show the populated combobox(left) and a QCompleter on the column 1 (right).

[image]
[image]

This example works fine as long as the model columns for the QComboBox and QCompleter are the same. But it would be much more intuitive for this example for QCompleter to use column 0 (city/state), but still have QComboBox use column 1 (airport code). Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox,
                             QCompleter, QTableView, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel, QSqlDatabase)
import sys
import sqlite3

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)

        fid = open('example.db', 'w')
        fid.close()

        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName('example.db')
        db.open()
        query = QSqlQuery(db)

        query.exec_('CREATE TABLE "airports" ("city" TEXT, "code" TEXT)')

        airports = [('Aberdeen, SD','ABR'), ('Abilene, TX','ABI'),
                    ('Adak Island, AK','ADK'), ('Akiachak, AK','KKI'),
                    ('Akiak, AK','AKI'), ('Akron/Canton, OH','CAK'),
                    ('Akuton, AK','KQA'), ('Alakanuk, AK','AUK'),
                    ('Alamogordo, NM','ALM'), ('Alamosa, CO','ALS'),
                    ('Albany, NY','ALB'), ('Albuquerque, NM','ABQ')]
        for item in airports:
            sql = 'INSERT INTO airports(city, code) VALUES(?, ?)'
            query.prepare(sql)
            query.addBindValue(item[0])
            query.addBindValue(item[1])
            query.exec_()

        query.exec_('SELECT * FROM airports')

        model =  QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery(query)

        self.cb = QComboBox(parent = self)
        self.cb.setModel(model)
        self.cb.setModelColumn(1)
        self.cb.setView(QTableView(self.cb))
        self.cb.setGeometry(50,50, 250, 50)
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.indexer)

        self.label = QLabel(parent = self)
        self.label.setGeometry(20,200, 250, 50)

        self.cb.view().setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.cb.setEditable(True)

        self.completer = QCompleter()
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(False)
        self.cb.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.completer.setModel(model)
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(1)
        self.completer.setPopup(QTableView())
        self.completer.popup().setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.completer.popup().setMinimumHeight(500)

        self.completer.activated.connect(self.activatedHandler)

    @pyqtSlot(QObject)        
    def activatedHandler(self, arg):
        pass

    def indexer(self, idx):
        self.label.setText('%d' % idx)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow(None)
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I change the QCompleter to use column zero, i.e.

```
self.completer.setCompletionColumn(0)
```

then the correct combobox row is selected after the completer does it's thing, but the displayed text is the city/state and not the aiport code(below left and middle). Further if the user presses enter then the combobox tries to use the text to select a row, but cannot find it and resets combobox row to -1. (below right). Is there any way to change this behavior so that the desired text (airport code) is shown in the combobox?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you explain the "enter", I can't reproduce it

Comment: In the picture with Alamoso, CO the cursor for the combobox is at the end of that string. If you press the enter/return key then the combobox tries to make that text the active row, but it cannot find it because it is searching in a different column. So it resets to -1. It looks like your CustomCompleter fixes this behavior. :-)

Comment: I only reproduce the "-1" only when there is no item selected in the popup of the QCompleter and press the enter, in your image there is one selected so I get the selected row with it. With my solution the second issue still persists?

Comment: @eyllanesc, with your solution the second issue does NOT persist. Because combobox has correct text from your custom class, it does not reset after return is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the QCompleter uses the text of the model completionColumn to do the search and the autocomplete, so therefore there are conflicts, a possible solution is to override the pathFromIndex method and return the appropriate text

```
class CustomCompleter(QCompleter):
    def pathFromIndex(self, index):
        sibling_index = index.sibling(index.row(), 1)
        return super().pathFromIndex(sibling_index)
```

```
self.completer = CustomCompleter()
```

<sub>I can't reproduce the second issue so I'll wait for OP feedback.</sub>

Comment: Nice solution. It never would have occured to me to override pathFromIndex from the [way they describe it in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#pathFromIndex). All the paths and roles and other stuff is really confusing.

Comment: @bfris That method in simple words gets the QModelIndex selected from the view(popup) and returns the text used for "autocomplete", by default it uses the completionColumn and the role Qt.EditRole