# PyQt5 Custom QCompleter

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qcompleter

My Question is regarding QCompleter, Following minimum working code using QCompleter executes succesfully, and the output is also given below,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QCompleter,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget
)
import pandas as pd

data2={'Name': ['Tom', 'John','Pakistan',"word1","word2","Ten"], 
    'Description': ["Cruise",
            "cena",
            "Capital is Islamabad", 
            "synonum of word1",
            "example of word2",
            "10",
            ]}  
df=pd.DataFrame(data2)

class mywin(QWidget): # doesnot work with QMainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywin,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        self.setWindowTitle('application')
        self.setGeometry(200,200,400,200)
        
        self.l=QLineEdit()
        completer=QCompleter(df.Name)
        self.l.setCompleter(completer)
        vbox.addWidget(self.l)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

def mymain():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=mywin()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    mymain()
```

and the output is shown below

[image: output of above code]

Now, I want QCompleter to show the second column which is 'Description', It should find elements based on 1st column but suggest the corresponding second column entry.
For Example: If 'Tom' is typed/selected, the QCompleter should show 'Cruise' only, if "John" is selected then the QCompleter should enter "Cena" only in the QLineEdit QObject (QLineEdit should show Cena only when John is typed/selected, Cruise only when Tom is typed/selected), and same for all other entries.

Please Note: that completer=QCompleter(df.Description) is not the answer i am looking for.

Comment: What is your actual question? SO isn't a code writing service. I suggest you read the QCompleter docs (especially the part about [handling tree models](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#handling-tree-models)), and make a genuine attempt to find a solution by yourself. Also, a little searching will quickly find similar examples on SO (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24687620/984421)).

Comment: I'd say that your proposed approach is not very intuitive from the UX perspective. I can understand the need for "suggestions", but what about conflicting values that come from different columns? For instance, consider a list of names that includes "John Wayne" and "Dwayne Johnson": what should the list suggest, when the user types "John"? That said, providing such an advanced and complex behavior *is* feasible, but not easy, and I'm afraid that the existing QCompleter implementation would require so many changes that you'd get better results by implementing a completion system on your own.

Comment: @musicamante for the conflicting values (in case of John Cena and John Wayn), all values from the second column will be displayed in the drop down menu (Cena and Wayn) using self.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion), and the user can select from the suggested values (either Cena or Wayn).  The selected value (either Cena or Wayn) is then displayed on the QLineEdit.

Comment: @AyyazAzeem Please read my comment more carefully: the cases in my example were "John Wayne" and "Dwayne Johnson", meaning that **both** could have results from the name ***OR*** the surname if the user started typing "john", since it would match the name for the former and the surname for the latter.

Comment: @musicamante First Column contains John, John, Dwayne, Dwayne and second column contains Cena, Wayne, Johnson, Rock, now when ever the user enters John, the program should suggest corresponding entries (Cena and Wayne) from the second column, if the user enter Dwayne, the user is suggested (Johnson and Rock), 
the QCompleter should search on the entries of first column but make suggestions of corresponding 2nd column entries. 
ur getting confused on the contents of the columns, the QCompleter should search in the first column but suggest corresponding items from the second column.

Comment: @AyyazAzeem with all due respect, no, I'm not getting confused. I've understood what you want to do, and it's that behavior **exactly** that I find really confusing: I'd find it very, **very** annoying as a user, as it's completely counter intuitive. I'd suggest yout to put aside any abstract example and stick to the point, because this is probably one of the situations for which the final purpose really matters: what is the actual application of your case? What is the purpose of the suggestion? Are you trying to provide some sort of "keyword shortcuts"?

Comment: @musicamante there could a number of applications, for example city name & zip code, city name & corrosponding airport, word & meaning, word & translation, first name last name, registration number & student name, .. what my application requires is stated in the original question at the top, i want to enter text & want QCompleter to search on the entered text (from first column) and suggest the corrosponding entry from the second column, i implemented [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162443/multicolumn-model-for-qcompleter?rq=1) in my code,but it did not work as per my requirement

Comment: @AyyazAzeem I realize the possible applications, and I still believe that such behavior is not a good one from the UX perspective, as the suggestion should also *display* the match of typed text in order to provide better context for the selection. That said, it's a matter of opinion (and, obviously, your choice), so please edit your question and show us how you actually tried the solution in the other link.